# Error loading player Could not load player configuration

Tags: video, jwplayer

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD 
 XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"             
 http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/94YoJHjcEeOOfCIACmOLpg.js"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id='playerCSXHVkOpDsGF'></div>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('playerCSXHVkOpDsGF').setup({
    file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Frg07De0Yeo',
    title: 'upup batangas budget hearing part2',
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9',
    fallback: 'false',
    primary: 'flash'
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi Guys I've got problem with JW player, this is my first time to create a website and my boss wants me to embed a video in the website using JW player but that code that JW player gives to me is not working. It always shows Error loading player Could not load player configuration. Please help me am a beginner. I m using html and adobe dreamweavercs6 is my aplication used.

Comment: Do not use dreamweaver. Learn html instead.

Comment: Can you provide a link?